# Mapping properties of the function $f: \mathbb { R } ^ { 2 } \rightarrow \mathbb { R }$ defined by $f ( x , y ) = x + y$,

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb { R } ^ { 2 } \rightarrow \mathbb { R }$ be a function
defined by $f ( x , y ) = x + y$, then
which of the following is/are true

1) $f$ maps open sets to open Sets

2) $f$ maps closed sets to closed sets

3) $f$ maps dense sets to dense sets

4) $f$ maps discrete Sets to discrete sets

Since $f$ is harmonic, we have $f$ is an open map, Also by using convergence of the sequence and continuity of $f$, we have 3. But what about closed sets and discrete sets

Comment: 2 is true . because f is sum of two maps. $f_1(x,y)=x$ and $f_2(x,y)=y$

Comment: 2 is false..1 is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $D=\bigl\{(0,0)\bigr\}\cup\left\{\left(n,\frac1n-n\right)\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ is discrete, but $f(D)=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$, which is not discrete.

And the set $C=\left\{\left(n,\frac1n-n\right)\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ is closed, but $f(C)=\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$, which is not closed.